# Align images in github-flavored-markdown

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I have these badges in my Github repo:

[image]

How can I make them align to left (the 2 above) and to right the one under?

They are in the format `![description](url)`

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're trying to do? "align to left (the 2 above) and to right the one under" is very hard to understand.

Comment: @Chris, there are 3 badges in the image above. 2 on top, same size each, and the large one with many browsers. I would like to one under (that has 5 browsers) align/float to the right of the other two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use html table (since markdown table in GFM doesn't support merged cell)

this, for instance, seems to align the pictures properly within a `README.md` file.

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <td align="left"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/cat-commerce/48/add-icon.png"/></td>
    <td align="right"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/cat-commerce/48/info-icon.png"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/shwz/disney/512/pumbaa-icon.png"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Result:

[image: result]

In your case:

```
<table>
  <tr >
    <td><img src="https://api.travis-ci.org/axemclion/grunt-saucelabs.png?branch=master"/></td>
    <td align="right"><img src="https://saucelabs.com/buildstatus/grunt-sauce"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><img src="https://saucelabs.com/browser-matrix/grunt-sauce.svg"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Which gives:

[image: with svg]

Comment: `+1` for nice images and a solution that does work with `<img>` tags. Still I can't get it to work with those badges. __[Here is a markdown example similar to mine](https://github.com/axemclion/grunt-saucelabs/blob/master/README.md)__

Comment: @Rikard Strange: That seems to work just fine in my `README.md`: see the markup I used to display your build status pictures in my extended and revised answer.

Comment: Ok, got It! Apparently it doesn't work with the markdown format: `![description](url)` but both SauceLabs and Travis have also the option of "good old" HTML. So, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Rikard I agree. I tried with markdown first, but couldn't get it to work. I fell back to HTML.